# A finite divisible group is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am having trouble seeing why a finite divisible group is necessarily trivial.  Why does this have to be the case?

Comment: Can someone explain me what "a finite divisible group" does mean? Thanks.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $n=|G|$. If $g\in G$, then by divisibility there exists $h\in G$ with $h^n=g$. But $h^n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $G$ is a finite divisible group and let $g\in G$, there is
some $g'\in G$ s.t $g'^{k}=g$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and for $k=|G|$
we get $g'^{|G|}=g$ thus $g=e$ and $G=\{e\}$